# ImageMagick: Merging two images with different Brightness/Contrast

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I am trying to layer one image over the other having different brightness using ImageMagick.

Original Image with high brightness:

[image: Original Image with high brightness]

After layering an other image on to it:

[image: After layering an other image on to it]

My Question is 
how to balance the brightness of the resulted image using ImageMagick.

Comment: I think you have got more serious issues than brightness and contrast to worry about, such as your masking and direction of light. This is more of a job for interactive software like Photoshop and pixel-by-pixel refinement than ImageMagick's formulaic, command-line interface.

Answer (score 0):

By using the [`-brightness-contrast`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#brightness-contrast) option:

```
convert image.png -brightness-contrast 50
```

The range of values is -100 to +100